# Importing modules in a remote session

Tags: powershell, module

We have one script server running Windows Server 2012 with PowerShell 4.0 and multiple other servers that run Windows Server 2008R2 with PowerShell 4.0.

What we're trying to do is use the function `Get-FSRMQuota` from the module `FileServerResourceManager` found on Server 2012 on the 2008R2 file servers. When in an RDP session on the 2008R2 file server, this can be easily done:

```
# From PowerShell on the file server:
New-PsSession $ScriptSever
Invoke-Command -Computer $ScriptSever {Import-Module FileServerResourceManager}
Invoke-Command -Computer $ScriptSever {Get-FSRMQuota}
```

However, all our scripts launch from the script server and are managed there. So we have a job that's initiated on the script server (2012) to run on the 2008R2 servers using `PS Remoting`. But from within this job it's not possible to import a module from the script server that initiated the job.

So my question, is there a way to import the module `FileServerResourceManager` from the script server into the remote session on the file server?

I hope I made it clear, as it's a bit difficult to explain. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj900651(v=wps.620).aspx, `FileServerResourceManager` is only available as of Windows 2012.

Comment: Yes i know that, but my question is can these CmdLets be made available in the remote session on the remote Win Srv 2008R2 server?

Comment: And the answer is no. When you are in remote session you are on the "target" computer, which is W2008R2 for you